# Checking a specific quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition

Suppose given a quantum state $$p^{1/2}|\uparrow\rangle+(1-p)^{1/2} |\downarrow\rangle$$ where $|\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\rangle$ denotes spin up and spin down. How to check that it is in the given state?

Comment: Versus what other state? If you mean, vs. all possible states, this isn't possible with just one copy of the state.

Answer (score 1):

As per preceding answers, you 'd typically need to test many copies of identically-prepared systems. But I'm guessing that answer doesn't address the sense of your question, as follows. Another answer is that instead of constructing test apparatus that accepts $\left|\uparrow\right>,\left|\downarrow\right>$ states, you'd change basis and construct a test apparatus for the states you've constructed.

That's best illustrated by an analogous example discussing photon polarization. Consider an $\left|x\right>,\left|y\right>$-basis for linearly polarized photons. And now you want to "check for the given state" $\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|x\right>+i\left|y\right>\right)$. Well, that's just right-circular polarization in the $\left|R\right>,\left|L\right>$-basis (right,left-basis). And there are calcite crystals that accept right-circularly polarized light, so you can directly test your one single system and see whether or not it's accepted.

Comment: That last example only works if you know for sure that the state is either R or L and nothing else. If you shine a single linearly polarised photon at your apparatus, though, it has a 50% chance of fooling you into thinking you've got R polarization.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yeah, but he's **said** he's prepared them that way. So the entire test is presumably unnecessary in the first place. If they're prepared as stated, then 100% will be accepted, guaranteed. I think he's just asking an intellectual question that wasn't precisely addressed by the original answers.

Comment: I disagree with your reading of the question - it is nowhere near that specific as far as I can see. But at the moment it's up for grabs until the OP clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You will need many such systems.  Measure the state of each of the systems and then find the ratio of the number of times you measure them to be up to number to times you measure them to be down.

Comment: No, this is not enough, because it yields no information about the phase between the up and down components.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  As I read the question, the coefficients on the basis vectors are both assumed to be positive real numbers, in which case one can in fact infer the phase.  Of course, it's a little mysterious how one could know that the coefficients are positive real numbers without knowing their values.

Comment: @WillO As pointed out in the comments, the question as posed is unclear, so if PhysLab wants to work within a certain restricted set of hypotheses (i.e. some information about the state is already known) then the answer should explicitly state those hypotheses. The problem you pose (i.e. the state is known to be of the form $|psi⟩=\sqrt{p}|↑⟩+\sqrt{1-p}|↓⟩$ but with unknown $p$) strikes me as particularly artificial.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  I agree 100% that the problem is particularly artificial.  But I do want to make clear that this is not "the problem I pose".  It is the problem that I think the OP is posing, and I like it as little as you do.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate the answer of @PhysLab a bit.

As soon as you make measurement the electron will go in spin up ($\uparrow$) or spin down ($\downarrow$) state and you will get 100% electron in one of the state. If you make measurements on the large number of such electrons then you will get the probability distribution of electron having $\uparrow$ or $\downarrow$ state.